# How to know if a Javascript promise is fulfilled or not?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I need to write a function that returns a boolean based on whether a promise is fulfilled or not at the moment that function is invoked. Obviously, I cannot `await` the promise (otherwise, it will always be fulfilled), I need to know **immediately** upon calling the function whether or not the promise is fulfilled (either `resolved` or `rejected`).

I've been poking around SO and the internet for a solution for this, but other than `util.inspect` from Node.JS that I cannot use, I haven't seen a reliable solution for this.

Any assistance would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Why do you think you need this? Maybe a cleaner design exists where you don't.

Comment: @Thomas I converted an existing code into a Promise. I cannot change the entire API now and I have to convert a function that returned a boolean up until now to deal with a promise instead of a state like before :/

Comment: That's what I thought. Async code tends to be contagious, so changing entire swathes of code at once is to be expected, sadly.